# Axiom Of Choice to create a sequence of right inverses

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to construct a sort of sequence of right inverses. My question is whether the construction uses the Axiom Of Choice correctly.

Suppose I have a sequence of surjective functions
$$
\ldots\stackrel{f_3}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}\stackrel{f_2}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}\stackrel{f_1}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}
$$
Assuming the Axiom Of Choice there exists a right inverse function $g_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_1(x)\in f_{1}^{-1}(x)$. Therefore we can define, using the Axiom Of Choice again, a function $g_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_2(x) \in f_{2}^{-1}(g_1(x))$. 
Note that $f_1\circ g_1 = \text{id}_\mathbb{R}$ and $f_1\circ f_2 \circ g_2 = \text{id}_\mathbb{R}$.

In general we construct:
\begin{align*}
g_1(x)&\in f_{1}^{-1}(x) \\
g_n(x) &\in f_{n}^{-1}(g_{n-1})(x)
\end{align*}
I want to use this construction to state that for each $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence of elements $(x_n = g_n(x_0))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n(x_n) = x_{n-1}$. However, to create the whole sequence I feel we need to use the Axiom Of Choice countably many times. Is this allowed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the axiom of choice infinitely many times. You're using it exactly twice to choose, uniformly, an inverse $g_n$ to $f_n$. Once to prove that each $f_n$ has an inverse, then again to choose the $g_n$'s.

Then you can use recursion, which does not use the axiom of choice at all, to define the function mapping $x\mapsto\langle g_n(x)\mid n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.